# XPages Runtime version reports WCT instead of DSI

Tags: eclipse, xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-extlib

We have an existing Domino 8.5.3 FP4 server that is being used for XPages application for the first time.  The latest Extension Library from OpenNTF has been installed, but the issue we're having appears to be with the standard XPages runtime.

A simple XPage is displaying:

```
Error 500
HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception
```

and in the xpages_exc_XXX.log:

```
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet
```

It appears to be due to WCT being reported as the version:

```
tell http osgi show version
XSP Runtime Version: [WCT8.5.3_FP4] 20130326.1400
```

What would cause WCT to be reported rather than DSI?  I read it should always be DSI for Domino XPages.

```
tell http osgi diag org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry
Cannot find bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.
```

The following files in D:\Lotus\Domino\osgi\rcp\eclipse\plugins appear to be have been updated after Domino was installed:

```
com.ibm.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.nl_6.2.3.20110815-1128.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.0.100.v20080427-0830.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.0.100.v20080427-0830.jar
```

Thanks

- Update 04 February 2014 09:45

I've performed the following:

```
tell http osgi diag org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet
Cannot find bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.
```

This does NOT list the following (which are displayed on a working server) - although bundles 0-7 and 10-152 are listed:

```
tell http osgi ss

8 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.0.100.v20080427-0830
Fragments=45
9 ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.0.100.v20080427-0830
```

Is there any further debugging I can do to determine why the bundles cannot be found?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the WCT vs. DSI label is the problem.  That's just an artifact of how IBM builds fix packs.  However, there does appear to be a problem with the set of OSGi plugins installed on your system.

It looks like it can't load equinox.http.registry because it can't find a required plugin -- equinox.http.servlet.  Have you tried investigating why the second plugin doesn't load?  In other words:

```
tell http osgi diag org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet
```

That might help you chase down the missing constraint.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I've update the question with the recent test I've done

Comment: Sorry, Gary.  It's not obvious to me what went wrong.  You said some plugins, including equinox.http.servlet, "appear to be have been updated after Domino was installed."  Perhaps OSGi can't load the plugin because it is somehow corrupt.  Only thing I can think of is to reinstall 8.5.3 and FP4.  Good luck.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the confirmation.  Reinstalling Domino was my next step but wanted to check first.